# Difference between Client Side API vs Server Side API

Tags: development

I am just going through this SharePoint 15 Training video and they are mentioning these terms again and again but am not sure with them though.

[MSDN Video talking about Sharepoint APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123626.aspx)

I think the Server Side API means we use the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll while developing a solution for SharePoint or an application developed using this API will be on a sharepoint server and we can use SPWeb or SPSite objects if we can use this api.

I'm not sure by client side API though. **What is the difference between these APIs and where can we use them?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Client Side APIs refer to the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx) that was introduced in SharePoint 2010.

There are basically 3 "flavors" of the Client Object Model: .NET, Silverlight and JavaScript (ECMAScript)

The Main advantage of the CSOM is that you do not need to be on the Server to use them in your program. The .NET client object model can be used in any Desktop or Web Client. The Silverlight CSOM can be used in silverlight applications (doh!) and you can call the JS Client Object Model directly from your web pages.

You can use them to perform a subset of operations which you can do from the Server Object Model. Here is a great tutorial on the .NET CSOM:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094(office.14).aspx

[image: Client Object Model Architecture]